# How to check url exist but has percentage value

Tags: mysql, select, underscore.js, conditional-statements, percentage

## Problem

### In Current DB

**URL_LIST** table

| **id** | **url** |
| --- | ---|
| 1 | https://example.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsite2.com%2my_name=ABC |

### Check url exist or not by these ways below

1. Original url (copy only)

   `select * from URL_LIST 
   where url = 'https://example.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsite2.com%2my_name=ABC';`
2. Adding slash for "%" and "_"

   `select * from URL_LIST 
   where url = 'https://example.com/?url=https\%3A\%2F\%2Fsite2.com\%2my_name=ABC';`
3. Removing "%" and "_"

   `select * from URL_LIST 
   where REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '%', ''), '_', '') = 'https://example.com/?url=https3A2F2Fsite2.com2myname=ABC';`

Before insert or update a record, I want to check that url exist or not.
Whatever I set search value the same with url value in DB, and added slash before percentage (%) sign and undercore sign (_), but still not work.

Result is always "not exist".
So what I can do is just insert new record, cannot update that records.

Note: Please don't tell me check existing by id, because I got urls from a csv file, then I want to check those urls exist in my DB or not. Then decide to insert or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all

I found my problem.

Reason is: I set **length** of url column is 255 (means: data in DB was cut the entire value of url when inserted), when **actual length** is longer.
After setting to 1024, I can check existing correctly.